# Replace removed event with plugin

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin

I used this event in Magento 1:- `sales_quote_config_get_product_attributes`.

In Magento 2 this event is removed, in `CHANGELOG.md` it's saying, use plugin instead of event.

How can i use this event as plugin in Magento 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event was used to modify the return value of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Config::getProductAttributes()`

This is now possible with an `after` plugin.

The class is now `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Config`, the method still `getProductAttributes()`

Plugins are documented here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 2):

You can see the existing code like

/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Config">
    <plugin name="append_sales_rule_keys_to_quote" type="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Plugin\QuoteConfigProductAttributes"/>
</type>
```

/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Plugin/QuoteConfigProductAttributes.php

```
public function afterGetProductAttributes(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Config $subject, array $attributeKeys)
{
    $attributes = $this->_ruleResource->getActiveAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $attributeKeys[] = $attribute['attribute_code'];
    }
    return $attributeKeys;
}
```

You can use like this in `Plugin` way ( Before, After and Around ) in your module. I hope you know how to create a basic `plugin` flow.

Hope this helps.